# Using Random in Python's list comprehension

Tags: python, list, random, list-comprehension

I have a list of words named `words` and I would like to generate a list of 100 three-words elements named `pwds`.
I want these 3 words to be randomly picked from the `words` list for each element of the `pwds` list, and I'd like to use list comprehension to do this.

This solution works :

```
pwds = [random.choice(words)+' '+random.choice(words)+' '+random.choice(words) for i in range(0,100)]
```

It generates a list that looks like : `['correct horse battery', 'staple peach peach', ...]`

But I was looking for a way that prevents repetiting 3 times `random.choice(words)`, so I tried this :

```
pwds = [(3*(random.choice(words)+' ')).strip() for i in range(0,100)]
```

But unfortunately, this solution makes each element having the same word three times (for example : `['horse horse horse', 'staple staple staple', ...]`), which is expected to happend.

Do you know a way to pick 3 random words **without repetition** *(EDIT : by "repetition", I mean the code repetition, not the random words repetition)* ?

EDIT : My question is different than the one it has been marked as duplicate of because I'm looking for using list comprehension here. I know how I could generate different numbers, I'm just looking for specific way to do it.

Comment: [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: This function is great, I came up with this solution : `pwds = [' '.join(random.sample(words,3)) for i in range(0,100)]`. But this function prevents the possibility that the same word occurs 2 or 3 times in the same element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the words to be able to repeat within each triplet, I think what you want is something like:

```
pwds = [" ".join(random.choice(words) for _ in range(3)) for _ in range(100)]
```

Note the use of `_` to indicate that we don't actually use the numbers generated by either `range`, and the fact that `range(0, n)` is the same as `range(n)`.

A somewhat shorter example:

```
>>> import random
>>> words = ['correct', 'horse', 'battery', 'staple']
>>> [" ".join(random.choice(words) for _ in range(3)) for _ in range(5)]
['horse horse correct', 
 'correct staple staple', 
 'correct horse horse', 
 'battery staple battery', 
 'horse battery battery']
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for your coding advice too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the join function and a list comprehension to not repeat random.choice

```
pwds = [' '.join([random.choice(words) for _ in range(3)]) for _ in range(100)]
```

Comment: Although it is the same answer than jonrsharpe, yours helps to understand that we are using a nested list comprehension, which I didn't understand at first.

Comment: Absolutly, jonrsharpe was just faster than me.

Comment: Actually, this is slightly better than my approach, as passing a list (rather than the bare generator expression) to `str.join` is more efficient - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/3001761

Comment: @SeevenByakko no problem. It won't make much difference with three items, but it's worth knowing about.